# expanding React ecosystem similar to Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Angular appears to come with everything which for the client-side. On the other hand, React comes by itself. Are there any common consensus on how to get expand React/React Native with typescript in order to get a similar experience as with Angular. Are there any books?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for types support, of course React can be now used with Typescript. [It's just an option to activate when you create the app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/).

Angular comes with "lot's of things" indeed, which means sometimes more than necessary, at the cost of the complexity.

It does not comes with "everything" however. You have to add manually UI toolkit like Angular material, or state management like NgRx.

React on the other side let you choose if you need a library or just keep VanillaJS.
For example, to make HTTP calls:
- Angular provides HttpClient which forces you to use RxJs
- ReactJS let's you use the Fetch API without RxJs, or add a [library that suits you](https://blog.bitsrc.io/comparing-http-request-libraries-for-2019-7bedb1089c83)

That's why there is no common consensus: every apps have different needs so it's impossible to make the "perfect framework with everything inside".

However, here is a [short list of most common used libs with ReactJS](https://x-team.com/blog/8-best-and-most-popular-react-libraries-in-2019/).

Comment: Thank you, I think Angular allows to update the app to a newer release of Angular. Has  React anything like this?